# Create new Record Error

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

HI any help please  I have this code but create d'ont work  (odoo 10)

```
 for obj in self.browse(self):
                backup_status = 'Backup completed successfully at path : %s ' %(tar_file_path)
                self.env['db.backup.line'].create({
                 'backup_id' : obj.id,
                 'name' : obj.name,
                 'date_time' : time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                 'message' : backup_status,
                 'automatic' : automatic,
                 'done_by' : user_id,
                 'path' : tar_file_path,
                 'file_size' : str(os.path.getsize(tar_file_path)),                                 
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to create a one2many relation, then you must give the related field value. else you cant see that on view. please check the db tables and whether the data is updating. or if you think this is an security issue, then try to create as superuser.
like

```
self.env['db.backup.line'].sudo().create({...})
```

.
kindly update question with logs if you have any for more help

Comment: @ Burmese Yes one2many relation  but  I  give the related field                              
                                                                                                       
                                                                                                   
 history_line = fields.One2many('db.backup.line', 'backup_id', 'History', readonly=True)

Comment: class db_backup_line(models.Model):
    _name = 'db.backup.line'
    backup_id = fields.Many2one('db.autobackup.ept','Backup')
    name = fields.Char('DB Name', size=100)

Comment: self already will be a browsable object. no need to browse again. make sure code enters in loop

Comment: ok :  for obj in self  and what about create({
                 'backup_id' : obj.id,
                 'name' : obj.name,    it right or   backup_id : obj.id  without ' '

Comment: codes seems to looking good and working, EIther if I need to regenerate the error to find your problem, or you have to gave me the logs. and also please check the db table @Guesmi

Comment: always d'ont work I put class here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353716/create-record-error